# Different baggage allowance on two legs of a flight (TAP/LOT)

Tags: air-travel, luggage, fees-and-charges

I am going to fly from Lisbon to Warsaw.
I booked a flight that will do Lisbon-Bucharest with TAP who allows 1 piece of 23Kg (50 pounds) plus 1 extra of 10Kg (22 pounds)because I am an University Student, then I will continue my journey by getting a plane in Bucharest to Warsaw with LOT Polish Airlines who allows 1 piece of 23Kg and has no information about extra baggage for University students. The flights were booked together.

Am I going to be charged with an extra piece of luggage (10Kg) by LOT Polish Airlines?

Comment: http://consumertraveler.com/today/with-international-checked-baggage-on-code-share-flights-which-airlines-rules-apply/

Comment: Is this one ticket for both flights, or two separate tickets?

Answer (score 3):

It is my experience that flights on multiple airlines follow the rules of the first airline. This holds even when I have to recheck the baggage with the second airline after clearing customs. Last month I checked in with LAN which has free baggage allowance, flew to the US, then after customs checked in with  Air Canada which charges for the first bag, and was not charged. However I recommend you confirm this with your airlines to be sure.

Also consider carrying the 10kg item yourself if it is small enough, thus removing the problem on the second leg.

Answer (score 1):

Because this journey does not involve the United States, the baggage allowance will follow the "Most Significant Carrier" rule, under IATA Resolution 302.

Cathay Pacific helpfully [posts the Resolution online](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/en_GB/travel-information/baggage/check-in-baggage/most-significant-carrier-msc-for-multi-carrier-journey.html). In this case you are travelling wholly within an IATA sub area ("Europe") **so the baggage allowance of the first international carrier applies to the whole baggage journey** (from check in to collection).

However the second piece may actually be a "fee waiver" rather than a bag included as an allowance on your ticket. In this case, it is possible LOT might try to charge you for it, but I suspect they would not actually notice (the baggage delivery computer is not very clever).